# Redirect to external URL on click in VUE.JS

Tags: html, vue.js, redirect

```
      <h3 :class="{'active': game.Desktop}"
        @click="game.gameAchievements = false, game.gameCreation = false, enJin.audioController.play('take')"
        @mouseenter="enJin.audioController.play('cardHover')">Desktop App</h3>
```

I have the issue, that I somehow cannot get this button to a external webpage. I already tried basic things like this.$router.push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exemple in Vuejs3 you can

```js
const redirect = () => {
  window.location.href="https://some-url.com"
}
```

And add this function into `@click` on your HTML element

```html
<button @click="redirect()">
  Redirect
</button>
```